# Assign customer group to guest (Prestashop 1.4.1)

Tags: prestashop

On Prestashop:

I have a store that I'm working with "guest checkout"; I'm interested on create some customer groups but can assign it to guest users; somebody know to work with assignment group with guests?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Once you login, go to the Customer tab. Under the tab you should create a new group under the "Group" sub-tab. Once you done that, go back to the "Customer" tab. Scroll down and you will see names of the customers. Click on the small pencil icon (action), and scroll to the bottom.

You'll see "Default" and then then check the group you want the person to associated with.